Vercel firewall Next.js Deny php extension in requests
I have hobby Next.js site that is getting about 40,000 bot requests for php files. The bots are scanning for wordpress vulnerabilities on a php platform.  I want to use Vercel's firewall custom rules to block all php requests. Can someone help me block all requests to *.php in Vercel Firewall Custom Rules?
I have limited success using custom rule
request -> contains -> /wp-content -> Deny
This rule seems to work fine. It blocked 35 requests yesterday, only 39,965 more to block.  Instead of trying to block all the wp folders I thought it would just be easier to deny all php files.
I have tried the methods below to block php requests with very odd results. After implementing  each of the rules below I found that if I navigate in my browser to somesite/anyname.php the vercel firewall behaves as I would expect, it presents a forbidden error to my browser.
The problem is when I check Firewall logs it doesn't show that its blocking anything. As a matter of fact its marking the browser request as regular web traffic even though its showing my browser a forbidden response.
//Works as expected logs shows request denied and the rule that denied request.
request -> contains -> '/wp-content' -> Deny
//Blocks browser traffic logs traffic as valid in Firewall->
request -> contains -> '/[slug].php' -> Deny
//Blocks browser logs traffic as valid in firewall(live view)
request -> contains -> '/*.php' -> Deny
//Blocks browser traffic does not show traffic as denied in logs
request -> matches -> '.(?:php\d?| phtml|ini|xml|key|cache|sqlite|db|pem|lock)(?:$|?)$' -> Deny
Edit** I tested the regular expression and it wasnt correct so I have replaced it with .php$ just to keep life easy. Will report back when I have additional data
All of the methods that I have tested above block the browser with forbidden. The 3 custom rules that I am using to block php extensions are blocking the browser but are marking it as ordinary web traffic in the logs, so it is still marked as a valid edge request.
It really peaves me I have this little hobby site with 1,000 visitors a month and take a 40k hit in edge requests from bots scanning for a security vulnerabilities. On a stack I am not even using no less! I have the bandwidth for the scans, its just the principle of the thing.

It appears to me that vercel writes the requests to the logs even if the requests return 403 forbidden. That confused me a bit, but they are being denied even though the requests are logged.
At this point I have set up this configuration in the vercel firewall.
Rule 1
RequestPath --> MatchesExpression  --> .php$|.php7$
Rule 2
RequestPath --> MatchesExpression -->(wp-content|wp-admin|wp-login|cgi-bin|wp-includes|wp-trackback|wp-feed)
I did it this way because the logs show the bots looking for urls like site/wp-content/ or site/wp-includes/ without a php extension just a trailing slash
Today I had 1,000 requests denied with this setup so it seems to be working pretty well.
JA4 Digest requests are next on the menu.
